# Prevent backup reads from getting into linux page cache

Tags: linux, caching, memory-management, backup

AFAIK all disk reads on linux get into the page cache.

Is there a way to prevent reads (done by a backup process) to get in to the page cache?

Imagine:

- A server runs fine, since most operations don't need to touch the disk, since enough memory is available.
- Now the backup process starts and does a lot of reading. The read bytes get into the memory (page cache) although nobody wants to read the same bytes again in the next hours.
- The backup data fills up the memory and more important pages from the cache get dropped.
- Server performance gets worse since more operations need to touch the disk, because the relevant pages were dropped from the cache.

My preferred solution:

- Tell linux that the reads done by the backup process don't need to be stored in the page cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- if you re using **rsync** there is the flag `--drop-cache` according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105203/how-can-i-limit-the-cache-used-by-copying-so-there-is-still-memory-available-for)
- the [nocache](https://github.com/Feh/nocache) utility which

> minimize the effect an application has on the Linux file system cache
>
> Use case: backup processes that should not interfere with the present state of the cache.

- using **dd** there is direct I/O to bybass cache according to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122857/can-i-copy-large-files-faster-without-using-the-file-cache)
- the **dd** also has the option `nocache` option check the command `info coreutils 'dd invocation'`for details